# javascript form validation - letters only

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have written a code that only allows letters to be typed into a text field, but it is not working. Can you help me spot the errors, and find a solution please.

```js
function allLetter(inputtxt) {
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if(inputtxt.value.match(letters)){
      return true;
  }else{
      alert('Please input letters only');
      return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <input name="Forename" type="text" required="required" id="Forename2" onclick="allLetter(document.form1.text)"/>
</form>
```

Comment: please add the code to the question.

Comment: Please review the how to ask a good question guide. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And welcome to stack overflow

Comment: Click on edit link under your question and past your code , refer (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Your code would only run when you click on the field, not when you type in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the event to `onkeyup`, because with `onclick` the input has not taken place and the value could not be tested.

Then you need to hand over the element, the easiest is to use `this` as reference to the actual element.

For the search of not wanted character, you could check the whole string for the wanted characters.

```js
function allLetter(inputtxt) {
    var letters = /^[a-z]*$/i;
    if (!inputtxt.value.match(letters)) {
        alert('Please input letters only');
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <input name="Forename" type="text" required="required" id="Forename2" onkeyup="allLetter(this)" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you but this method did not allow all letters to be typed

Comment: which ones are not checked?

Comment: All letters can be typed now, however the message pops up even when i press backspace. please may you help me with this.

Answer (score 4):

why not just use a pattern input

```
<form action="#" id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <input name="Forename" type="text" required="required" id="Forename2" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" />
</form>
```

Comment: I think this `pattern="[A-Za-z]"` only matches 1 letter

Answer (score 0):

`document.form1.text` is not a valid way to access your text input field. `document.forms[0].elements['Forename']` works. Try reading up on the document and the Form objects on MDN for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern to do what you want to do.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

```
<form action="#" id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <input name="Forename" type="text" required="required" id="Forename2" pattern="^[A-Za-z]+$" />
</form>
```

But note that such code should be validated server side on submit. It's trivial to override html input patterns and javascript.  So a server must validate all inputs on `post`.

You can try it out there https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern

Comment: thank you! does this mean that it does not require javascript?

Comment: Yep, no JavaScript needed for this specific validation.